# How can I restore a local backup of WhatsApp to a specific data profile created using Titanium backup app?

Tags: rooting, whatsapp-messenger, titanium-backup

In Titanium Backup app I have multiple data profiles for WhatsApp. I am using WhatsApp in 1st data profile and I need to restore a local backup of another WhatsApp number to 2nd data profile. How can I do it without uploading it to Google drive ? Where are the data of apps stored for each Titanium Backup profile ?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this?